# Getting value map is not a member of Object when doing getOrElse with Future in my Play2 app

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to do a for comprehension when calling my mongo instance with ReactiveMongo. The method should check if any result is returned, if not return Future(NotFound). But I'm getting an error that I don't understand.

```
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/Projects/reco_play/parser/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /Users/Projects/reco_play/parser/app/controllers/Application.scala:94: value map is not a member of Object
[error]           }.getOrElse(Future(NotFound))
[error]                      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

**Imports:**

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.Logger
import play.modules.reactivemongo.{ReactiveMongoPlugin, MongoController}
import models.{Company}
import reactivemongo.api.collections.default.BSONCollection
import reactivemongo.bson.{BSONObjectID, BSONDocument}
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import scala.concurrent.{Future, ExecutionContext}
```

**Method:**

```
def showEditForm(id: String) = Action {
    implicit request =>
      implicit val reader = Company.CompanyReader
      Async {
        val objectId = new BSONObjectID(id)
        val cursor = collection.find(BSONDocument("_id" -> objectId)).cursor[Company]

        for {
          maybeCompany <- cursor.headOption
          result <- maybeCompany.map { company =>
              Ok(views.html.editForm(Some(id), Company.form.fill(company)))
          }.getOrElse(Future(NotFound))
        } yield result
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I looked at your example more and you are right it's a different issue than what I originally answered with.  First, try changing your for-comp to this:

```
    for {
      maybeCompany <- cursor.headOption
    } yield {
       maybeCompany.map{company => 
        Ok(views.html.editForm(Some(id), Company.form.fill(company)))
      }.getOrElse(NotFound)
    }
```

The issue you are seeing had to do with mixing types in your for-comp.  You started the for-comp with a `Future` and then you tried to switch to an `Option` for the next step.  This is an unfortunate feature of for-comps in that whatever type you start with on the first line is the same type you have to continue with throughout the comprehension.  This is because you can not `flatMap` from `Future[T]` to `Option[T]` which is what would happen in the for-comp you had.  Another way to do it would be as follows:

```
    for {
      maybeCompany <- cursor.headOption
      result <- Promise.successful(maybeCompany.map { company =>
          Ok(views.html.editForm(Some(id), Company.form.fill(company)))
      }).future
    } yield result.getOrElse(NotFound)
```

In this approach, on the second step of the for-comp, I'm wrapping the `Option` result in a successfully completed `Future`, which is the correct type to use for continuing the comprehension.

Comment: Right, it might help to know that the for comprehension is really syntactic sugar for a call to `map`. (and in some cases `filter`, and `flatMap`... but never mind that now.)  So your example is equivalent to `cursor.headOption.map { x => x.map { ... }}`.  You're double mapping. :)

Comment: hmm in this case cursor.headOption will return Future[Option[Company]]
and maybeCompany.map {
          company => Ok(views.html.editForm(Some(id), Company.form.fill(company)))
        } should return an Option[Result]. I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: Check out this demo app https://github.com/jkyamog/reactivemongo-demo-app/blob/b3a8a5cb35843e59811c56d10b22edcd4adb6c8a/app/controllers/Application.scala

Comment: Modified my answer to be more in line with the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try something like this.

```
  for {
    maybeCompany <- cursor.headOption
    result <- maybeCompany.map { company =>
      Promise.successful(
        Ok(views.html.editForm(Some(id), Company.form.fill(company)))
      ).future
    }.getOrElse(Future(NotFound))
  } yield result
```